# C++: What is the difference between ostream and ostringstream?

Tags: c++, ostream, ostringstream

What is the difference between ostream and ostringstream? When would you use one versus the other?

Comment: also ostringstream is a derived class from ostream

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Put succinctly: `ostringstream` provides a `streambuf`, `ostream`
requires the user to provide one.

To understand the implications, it's necessary to understand a little
how streams work, and I'm not sure that there's a good explanation of this on the Web.  The basic abstraction
of `ostream` is formatting textual output.  You give it an `int` or a
`double` (or a user defined type—more on that later), and it 
convert it into a stream of characters, of type `char`.  What it does
with that stream depends on the `streambuf` which is attached to it;
this is an example of the strategy pattern, where `streambuf` is an
abstract base class of the strategy[1].  The standard provides two
implementations of `streambuf`, `filebuf` and `stringbuf`; in practice,
in all but the most trivial applications, you'll probably have some that
you implement yourself.

When outputting, you always use `ostream`; it's the class over which the
`<<` operators are defined.  You're formatting your data into a stream
of characters, and you don't really care where the stream ends up.

When creating an instance: if you create an `ostream`, you must provide
it with a `streambuf` yourself.   More often, you'll create an
`ofstream` or an `ostringstream`.  These are both "convenience" classes,
which derive from `ostream`, and provide a `streambuf` for it (`filebuf`
and `stringbuf`, as it happens).  Practically speaking, *all* they do is
provide the necessary `streambuf` (which affects the constructor and the
destructor, and not very much else); in the case of `ofstream`, there
are also a few extra functions which forward to additional functions in
the `filebuf` interface.

It's usual (but by no means required) when you define your own
`streambuf` to provide convenience overloads of `ostream` (and
`istream`, if relevant), along the same lines as `ofstream` or
`ostringstream`.

By the same token, when creating an instance, it's usual to use one of
the "convenience" derived classes, rather than to use `ostream` directly
and provide your own streambuf.

And if all of this seems complicated: the iostream classes use just
about all of the facilities of C++ (virtual functions, templates and
function overloading all play an important role).  If you're just
learning C++, don't worry too much about it: just use `ofstream` or
`ostringstream` when you construct an instance, but pass around
references to `ostream`.  And as you learn about techniques like virtual
functions, templates and operator overloading, return to the iostreams
to understand the role they play in making code more flexible.

---

[1] For various reasons, `std::streambuf` is not actually abstract.  But
the implementations of the virtual functions in it are useless;
extraction always returns EOF, and insertion always fails.

Answer (score 16):

Here is nice view of the Inheritance Hierarchy for C++ Stream Classes :) 
[This](http://www.dyn-lab.com/articles/c-streams.html) article  at the section 
 `3.1  ofstream and ostringstream` has what you need.

In essence : The `ofstream` class makes it possible to `write data to files using stream operations` and the `ostringstream` class makes it possible to `write to strings`.

[image]

Comment: There are some (obvious) errors at the bottom of your hierarchy: the classes which derive from `iostream` are `fstream` and `stringstream`.  (In practice, of course, `fstream` and `stringstream` are almost never used.)

Answer (score 6):

`ostream` is more general (subclasses support writing to different places), `ostringstream` is a specific one writing to a `string`

Answer (score 3):

`ostream` has no `rdbuf` implementation behind it, whereas `ostringstream` uses a stringbuf. Tried documentation?

Comment: Sorry... I did look at the documentation but I am still new to C++.  I have seen various uses of ostream and ostringstream but I was not sure of the difference.  Seems like my question is too basic for this site.  Maybe I'll withdraw it.

Comment: It's not about question being too basic,it's more about the answer being readily available. I'm glad to hear you actually *have* tried looking for an answer.

Comment: Of course I googled... but reading a documentation page like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/ isn't straightforward to someone new to C++. Plus, the second question on when one is used over the other has been mostly ignored by the other answers.

Comment: Because the difference in functionality should put you on the right track regarding the use. `ostringstream` is used when you need stream stuff into `string`, whereas `ostream` is mostly used as a type for a parameter (referenced) when the callee is stream implementation agnostic.

Comment: Err... the page you link says "ostringstream provides an interface to manipulate strings as if they were output streams". The very first sentence. Is it not straightforward?

Comment: And "ostream objects are stream objects used to write and format output as sequences of characters". I didn't understand what an output stream was at the time... but I have read much more about C++ since and got it now.