# Why is std::codecvt only used by file I/O streams?

Tags: c++, file, facet, ostream, codecvt

I've been implementing a codecvt for handling indentiation of output streams. It can be used like this and works fine:

```
std::cout << indenter::push << "im indentet" << indenter::pop << "\n im not..."
```

However, while I can imbue an `std::codecvt` to any `std::ostream` I was very confused when I found out that my code worked with `std::cout` as well as `std::ofstream`, but not for example for `std::ostringstream` even while all of which inherit from the base class `std::ostream`.

The facet is constructed normally, the code compiles, it doesn't throw any exceptions... It's just that none of the member functions of the `std::codecvt` are called.

For me that is very confusing and I had to spend a lot of time figuring out that `std::codecvt` won't do anything on non file I/O streams.

Is there any reason `std::codecvt` is not being used by all classes inherited by `std::ostream`?

Furthermore does anyone have an idea on which structs I could fall back on to implement the indenter?

Edit: this is the part of the language I'm referring to:

> All file I/O operations performed through std::basic_fstream use the std::codecvt<CharT, char, std::mbstate_t> facet of the locale imbued in the stream.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt

---

### Update 1:

I've made a small example illustrating my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

static auto invocation_counter = 0u;

struct custom_facet : std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t>
{
  using parent_t = std::codecvt<char, char, std::mbstate_t>;

  custom_facet() : parent_t(std::size_t { 0u }) {}

  using parent_t::intern_type;
  using parent_t::extern_type;
  using parent_t::state_type;

  virtual std::codecvt_base::result do_out (state_type& state, const intern_type* from, const intern_type* from_end, const intern_type*& from_next,
                                                               extern_type* to, extern_type* to_end, extern_type*& to_next) const override
  {
    while (from < from_end && to < to_end)
    {
      *to = *from;

      to++;
      from++;
    }

    invocation_counter++;

    from_next = from;
    to_next = to;

    return std::codecvt_base::noconv;
  }

  virtual bool do_always_noconv() const throw() override
  {
    return false;
  }
};

std::ostream& imbueFacet (std::ostream& ostream)
{
  ostream.imbue(std::locale { ostream.getloc(), new custom_facet{} });

  return ostream;
}

int main()
{
  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

  std::cout << "invocation_counter = " << invocation_counter << "\n";

  {
    auto ofstream = std::ofstream { "testFile.txt" };

    ofstream << imbueFacet << "test\n";
  }

  std::cout << "invocation_counter = " << invocation_counter << "\n";

  {
     auto osstream = std::ostringstream {};

     osstream << imbueFacet << "test\n";
  }

  std::cout << "invocation_counter = " << invocation_counter << "\n";
}
```

I would except `invocation_counter` to increase after streaming in the `std::ostringstream`, but it doesn't.

---

### Update 2:

After more research I found out that I could use `std::wbuffer_converter`. To quote https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wbuffer_convert

> `std::wbuffer_convert` is a wrapper over stream buffer of type
> `std::basic_streambuf<char>` which gives it the appearance of
> `std::basic_streambuf<Elem>`. All I/O performed through
> `std::wbuffer_convert` undergoes character conversion as defined by the
> facet Codecvt. [...]
>
> **This class template makes the implicit character conversion
> functionality of `std::basic_filebuf` available for any
> `std::basic_streambuf`.**

This way I can apply a facet to a `std::ostringstream`:

```
auto osstream = std::ostringstream {};

osstream << "test\n";
  
auto facet = custom_facet{};
  
std::wstring_convert<custom_facet, char> conv;
  
auto str = conv.to_bytes(osstream.str());
```

However, I lose the ability to concate facets using the streaming operator `<<`.

This confuses me even more why the `std::codecvt` is not implicity used by ALL output streams. All output streams inherit from `std::basic_streambuf` whose interface is suitable to using `std::codecvt`, which is just using an input and an output character sequence, fully implemented in `std::basic_streambuf`.

So why is the parsing of `std::codecvt` implemented in `std::basic_filebuf` instead of `std::basic_streambuf`? `std::basic_filebuf` inherits `std::basic_streambuf` after all...

Either I have some fundamental misunderstanding on how streams work in C++ or `std::codecvt` is poorly integrated in the standard. Maybe this is why it is marked as deprecated?

Comment: I don't know about the facet shenanigans, but maybe just use `std::format` and forget about iostreams altogether?

Comment: @PasserBy I've thought about using `std::format` but the advantage of using streams is, that it can use any stream it gets. I'm using the indenter in my json serializer which is able to write in any output stream using a reference of an object derived from `std::ostream`. That way I can serialize into `std::ofstream`, an `std::ostringstream`, or `std::cout`. Using `std::format` I would lose this flexibility, as the serializer is recursive calling each of the objects members to serialize.

Comment: C++98's std::codecvt is not deprecated, only the C++11's Unicode conversion locales derived from it are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::codecvt` facet was originally intended to handle I/O conversions between **disk** and **memory** character representation. Quoted from paragraph `39.4.6` of Bjarne Stroustrup's [The C++ Programming Language](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) fourth edition:

> Sometimes, the representation of characters stored in a file differs from the desired representation of those same characters in main memory. ... the **codecvt** facet provides a mechanism for converting characters from one representation to another as they are read or written.

The *intended* purpose was thus to use `std::codecvt` only for adapting characters between file (disk) and memory, which *partly* answers your question:

> Why is std::codecvt only used by file I/O streams?

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) we see that:

> All file I/O operations performed through `std::basic_fstream<CharT>` use the `std::codecvt<CharT, char, std::mbstate_t>` facet of the locale imbued in the stream.

Which then answers the question why `std::ofstream` (uses a file-based streambuffer) and `std::cout` ([linked to standard output FILE stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430116/14258355)) invokes `std::codecvt`.

Now, to use the high-level `std::ostream` interface you need to provide an underlying `streambuf`. The `std::ofstream` provides a `filebuf` and the `std::ostringstream` provides a `stringbuf` (which is not linked to the use of `std::codecvt`). See this post over the [streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12056871/14258355), which also highlights the following:

> ...in the case of ofstream, there are also a few extra functions which forward to additional functions in the filebuf interface

But, to invoke the character conversion functionality of a `std::codecvt` when you have a `std::ostringstream` which is a `std::ostream` with an underlying `std::basic_streambuf` you can use, as indicated in your post, the [`std::wbuffer_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wbuffer_convert).

You have only used the `std::wstring_convert` in your second update and not the `std::wbuffer_convert`.

When using the `std::wbuffer_convert` you can wrap the original `std::ostringstream` with a `std::ostream` as follows:

```cpp
// Create a std::ostringstream
auto osstream = std::ostringstream{};

// Create the wrapper for the ostringstream
std::wbuffer_convert<custom_facet, char> wrapper(osstream.rdbuf());

// Now create a std::ostream which uses the wrapper to send data to
// the original std::ostringstream
std::ostream normal_ostream(&wrapper);
normal_ostream << "test\n";

// Flush the stream to invoke the conversion
normal_ostream << std::flush;

// Check the invocation_counter
std::cout << "invocation_counter after wrapping std::ostringstream with "
                "std::wbuffer_convert = "
            << invocation_counter << "\n";
```

Together with the complete example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bv6sa3KMo), the output would be:

```
invocation_counter start of test1 = 0
invocation_counter after std::ofstream = 1
> test printed to std::cout
invocation_counter after std::cout = 2
invocation_counter after std::ostringstream (should not have changed)= 2
ic after test1 = 2
invocation_counter after std::ostringstream with std::wstring_convert = 3
ic after test2 = 3
invocation_counter after wrapping std::ostringstream with std::wbuffer_convert = 4
ic after test3 = 4
```

##### Conclusion

`std::codecvt` was intended for converting between **disk and memory representation**. That is why the `std::codecvt` implementation is only called with streams using an underlying `filebuf` such as `std::ofstream` and `std::cout`.
However, a stream using an underlying `stringbuf` can be wrapped using `std::wbuffer_convert` into a `std::ostream` instance which would then invoke the underlying `std::codecvt`.